Trying to get next level to load after all objects are destroyed
I have a simple unity game where a cannon at the bottom of the screen shoots bullets up at moving platforms at the top. I'm trying to get the next level to load after all of the platforms have been destroyed but I'm having trouble. I'm really new to coding any advice would be helpful.
(im just using Debug.Log to test)
ive tried two things:
public int DestroyedPlatforms;
public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("platform"))
{
       Destroy(other.gameObject);
       DestroyedPlatforms++;
       Debug.Log("Number of destroyed platforms: " + DestroyedPlatforms);
       if (DestroyedPlatforms >= 3) 
       {
          Debug.Log("load next level");
       }
   }
}

This is attached to the bullet prefab script. the problem is that it only works if one bullet destroys all three platforms. if I use one bullet on each platform, Unity doesn't register it as three platforms being destroyed.
I've also tried this:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] platform;
    void update()
    {
        platform = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("platform");
            if (platform == null)
            {
                Debug.Log("load next level");
            }
    }
}

I also tried using .Length == 0 and that didn't work.
For the first solution I think it gets messed up because it's attached to a prefab so I need to attach it to something else, but nothing else seems to work.

There are a lot of methods to do what you want, some easy, some harder. As you can expect, the harder ones are the best-practice preferred methods.
Since your game is simpler, I'll show you that, but keep in mind as you'll develop more sophisticated games, this might not be the best approach, especially because of hardcoding.
So assuming you're in your bullet or projectile class:
public static int DestroyedPlatforms;
public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("platform"))
    {
       Destroy(other.gameObject);
       DestroyedPlatforms++;
       Debug.Log("Number of destroyed platforms: " + DestroyedPlatforms);
       if (DestroyedPlatforms >= 3) 
       {
          Debug.Log("load next level");
       }
   }
}

Making DestroyedPlatforms static will mean there is one variable common to all bullets (or whatever class your static variable is in). Keep in mind this should be used only for simple games.
Let's say you want to prepare to get better so you don't want these lazy hacks. How to do this better?
Let's assume we have a game rules keeper. This can be a game manager, a score manager, a game rules manager, it depends on your game code architecture or the way you want your workflow to work.
internal class GameRules : UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour
{
    private static int RemainingPlatforms;

    internal static void SetRemainingPlatforms(int remainingPlatforms)
    {
        RemainingPlatforms = remainingPlatforms;
        CheckPlatforms();
    }
    
    internal static void AdjusRemainingPlatforms(int amount)
    {
        RemainingPlatforms += amount;
        CheckPlatforms();
    }
    
    private static void CheckPlatforms()
    {
        if (RemainingPlatforms <= 0)
            Debug.Log("Load next level");
    }
}

internal class Platform : UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        GameRules.AdjusRemainingPlatforms(-1);
    }
}

Here you basically notify your handler that when a platform is destroyed then the platform count should decrease. Of course you could use the collision or trigger engine events instead. The difference is, if you want some sort of "health" code, you can't say reduce the platform count by -1 on every collision, because you might want to destroy a platform after 3 hits on harder levels, not 1, but since the platform is destroyed (regardless of the number of hits it takes or the health that might be reduced), OnDestroy() will ensure you only do it when it goes out. Obviously you need to call SetRemainingPlatforms() when a new level is loaded (or if the player restarts or loads a saved game).
This looks a bit better right? But you can still "smell" a but of beginner code in it because of the statics. If you want to do it using instanced objects, read about the Singleton pattern. That link shows you how to do it in Unity. For other game engines, game frameworks or other languages, the short idea is to "play" around with constructors and destructors. But obviously a thorough read about the language you'll use as well as the API and framework you need is mandatory if you'll switch to something else.
Before we move on, keep in mind that while singletons are useful and you'll see TONS of tutorials or videos that show you whatever feature or method to do whatever in Unity will, at some point, contain some sort of "manager" class that will be a singleton, you might even think you need tons of them (InventoryManager, InputManager, PlayerManager etc.), do not abuse them. When you'll need to do some unit tests or fix bugs reported by users those singletons will be your downfall. Use them sparingly and only when needed. And in general, you won't need them that much. For example, an InventoryManager is a single instance but doesn't need to be a singleton since you should normally be able to access it from the current player. How to access the current player? Either form the game itself, if it's single player or from the HUD if it's multiplayer. How to access the HUD? Or Game? Again, depends on your game design, which is why I'd venture to guess that at least 5% (if not more) of the questions on Unity about whatever limitation or problem they have is a design issue at its root. Moving on.
So what if you don't want to use static vars and funcs and you don't want singletons? Let's see some design ideas. Small pseudo code, assuming you would have all those variables (or properties or Get*() functions in each)
internal class Platform : UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour
{
    public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Bullet"))
        {
            Bullet bullet = other.gameObject.GetComponent<Bullet>();
            Weapong weapon = bullet.weapon;
            HumanPlayer humanPlayer = weapon.owner;
            Game game = humanPlayer.world.game;
        }
    }
}

Imagine that hierarchy where everyone knows everything. There is practically no need for a singleton when you can just link A to B to C and see that C has a D and D knows about E and E can call a function in F. Sure, it might seem more complicated but it has its advantages. Again, the disadvantages might be at unit tests as you can't uncouple these objects (similar to singletons).
Of course, you still have the Find*() functions, just remember they are slow and might affect performance in a very complex real-time game (FPS, RTS, MMORPG etc.). FindGameObjectsWithTag() being the slowest. That's why examples show the Find*() functions used in Start() or Awake() only (meaning only once per instance). But in a FPS where you'd have a minigun, then 32 players, even a multiplayer game where all bullets must sync and considering the minigun is known to shoot a LOT of bullets really fast, even then calling FindGameObjectsWithTag() on every Start(), Awake() or OnTriggerEnter2D() might slow your game down.
As you probably guessed by now, there is not one  recipe, a single solution for every type of game or app. These are just some that I hope will help you as you progress and the more you'll learn (and that includes doing bad things, applying bad practices, learning about best practices, comparing the good, bad, in what game or project of yours each applies, take whatever lesson from each and so on) you'll get better and better.

Hey bro thank you for taking the time to write all of this it was very helpful. I appreciate it.

for taking the counters of destroyed platforms you should either use a static variable or a different class like gamemanager or simply a total different class only for handeling level completion logic.
I think you should use something like observer pattern. in bullet script when the bullet hits a platform an event should be triggered that platform is being hit.
also destroy the bullet if you want one bullet should hit one platform only.
bullet.cs be like
public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("platform"))
{
notify gamemanager that platform is being hit. 
destroy necessary objects. 
       
}
}

GameManager{
OnPlatformDestroy(){
//code for what to happen on platform destroy and also use the counter here
//you can also check whether all the platforms are destroyed or not
}
}

I think separating the responsibilities of classes and using events could make your things easier to debug and control
